# ORDER MySQL results BY date and also using LIKE

Tags: php, mysql

I have this table `request` with columns

```
request_id | users_ids | created
```

I need to get the results order by `created`, but get first the ones where user id do not exist inside `users_ids`.

Do i use something like `FIELD()` and `NOT LIKE`?

How do i do this?

Comment: `users_ids` contains `a,b,c,d,....,z` type comma-separated values? If so, the proper answer is you don't do this - you put them into their own separate child in a properly normalized design, and then your question basically goes away.

Comment: You need to give us more info. What do you mean by "not exist inside 'sers_ids"

Comment: 'users_ids' contains ids like 'po27 po34 po55' separated by spaces and there's not an order. I need the results order by 'created' but if user 'po33' is not inside 'users_ids' then i need this result first @MarcB

Comment: After studying DB-related scripting for over 6 months (slowly but surely, testing and testing and learning some more) and the many questions asked and answers given on SO, was happy to not have done anything like this. I like to take my time and learn/do things correctly.

Comment: In other words, your design is un-normalized, so you should fix the design. Read this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: So the best thing to do is to create another table just to store this ids? cause if i uses comma like this 'id1,id2,id3,...' it can give me a very big line and that is not a very good way, right?

Answer (score 0):

```
ORDER BY IF(FIND_IN_SET('111', user_ids)>0,1,0),created
```

Where '111' is your user id.
But, as Marc pointed in the comment to your question - you should avoid this by altering your schema design.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be storing `user_ids` in a field.  You should have a separate association/junction table.

You can do the `order by` this way (assuming that `user_ids` is comma delimited):

```
order by find_in_set($user_id, user_ids) = 0 desc,
         created
```

Edit:

If they are space separated, do one of the following:

```
order by find_in_set($user_id, replace(user_ids, ' ', ',')) = 0 desc,
         created;
```

or

```
order by concat(' ', user_ids, ' ') like concat('% ', $user_id'% '),
         created
```

Comment: *"assuming that user_ids is comma delimited"* - Nope, [`the plot thickens`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21861775/order-mysql-results-by-date-and-also-using-like#comment33096552_21861775)

Comment: users_ids is not comma saparated is sapareted by spaces is there an alternative? thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try breaking apart the query into two queries.

```
// QUERY 1
SELECT * FROM request WHERE users_ids = '' ORDER BY created

// QUERY 2
SELECT * FROM request WHERE users_ids != '' ORDER BY created
```